# How to send/receive sensor data from Genuino/Arduino101 with Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

I am trying to do a project based on Genuino/Arduino 101(CurieIMU) and Android in which I want to get sensors data like accelerometer,gyroscope(x,y and z) and send it to an android app with bluetooth. 
I don't know how to send/receive it and how to connect the devices with bluetooth low energy.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach bluetooth module to arduino and the use blutooth serial write to begin data transfer in digitalized form. that must be deserialized in the mobile side to get the data

Comment: so try integrating bluetooth based serial writer code to begin transmission of data

Comment: I can not understand how to send data with bluetooth. I searched some tutorials but i didn't find much information.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying complex thing try to do some basic stuff. just refer the link you can get some basic understanding of android and Bluetooth communication
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/user206876468/arduino-bluetooth-basic-tutorial-d8b737